# Program Shutdown Messes Up StreamWriter

Tags: c#, winforms, streamwriter

Im working on a little ATM program and I'm stuck on a *StreamWritter* problem.
On load, my program must use a *StreamReader* to read in 4 .txt files all located in my bin/debug. Then the user is asked to either Deposit or Withdraw money from the bank accounts located in the .txt files. Everything works fine for the *StreamReader* which loads all the bank accounts on program loading and for the *StreamWriter* to write the changes in the .txt files when I add/remove money.
My problem is when I close the program, the loading of the files works just fine but I can't write in the files anymore. My *StreamWriter* jumps straight to the *Catch* part and cannot be instantiated. How is that possible if it worked just fine on first use.
Heres the *StreamReader* Code :

```
    public bool ReadSavingAccount()
    {
        string strLine;
        string[] strArray;
        char[] charArray = new char[] { ',' };
        FileStream aFile;
        StreamReader sr;
        try
        {
            aFile = new FileStream("mySavingAccount.txt", FileMode.Open);
            sr = new StreamReader(aFile);

            strLine = sr.ReadLine();
            while (strLine != null)
            {
                strArray = strLine.Split(charArray);
                Savings monSave = new Savings(strArray[0], Convert.ToDouble(strArray[1]));
                mySavingAccount.Add(monSave);
                strLine = sr.ReadLine();
            }
            sr.Close();
            aFile.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

And the *StreamWrite* Code:

```
    public bool WriteSavingAccount()
    {
        FileStream aFile;
        StreamWriter sw;
        string myString;

        try
        {
            aFile = new FileStream("mySavingAccount.txt", FileMode.Create);
            sw = new StreamWriter(aFile);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

        foreach (Savings mySave in mySavingAccount)
        {
            myString = mySave.AccountNumber + "," + mySave.AccountBalance;
            sw.WriteLine(myString);

        }
        sw.Close();
        return true;
    }
```

Any idea what the problem could be ? 
Thanks in advance and let me know if you need any other parts of the code.

Comment: What is the exception you get?

Comment: If in ReadSavingAccount() method straight to the Catch part without close streamreader certainly writer method also got exception.

Comment: Never use `catch{return false;}`. It totally loses you the opportunity to find out what the exception was.Just get rid of the try/catch entirely.

Comment: Are you closing the 'aFile' filestream in your writeSavingsAccount ?

Comment: also why are you not disposing of the created objects.. have you considered doing fstreamSavingsAccount = new FileStream(fstreamSavingsAccount.ToString(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); I would try disposing of the objects and try that

Comment: I wonder also if you are getting a file already in use error try writing in your try catch Try{}catch (IOException ioEx) { console.WriteLine(ioEx.Message) or some logfile where you can capture the actual error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a second parameter of boolean to your StreamWriter call.  This is the append parameter.  True to append to the file, false to overwrite it.

```
sw = new StreamWriter(aFile, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your `StreamWriter` in a `using` statement to ensure it is closed properly.